# Java in CICS - Type 2 JDBC Connection giving error SQLCODE = -922, SQLSTATE = 42505, error tokens = PLAN ACCESS;00F30034

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, cics, db2-zos

In Java code while trying to get the connection using Type 2 Driver.

```
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:default:connection";

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL);
```

I am getting the below error.

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][50053][12311][3.69.56] T2zOS exception: [jcc][T2zos]T2zosConnection.flowConnect:execConnect:1425: DB2 engine SQL error, SQLCODE = -922, SQLSTATE = 42505, error tokens = PLAN ACCESS;00F30034 ERRORCODE=-922, SQLSTATE=42505

My DB2Conn properties:

```
 i DB2Conn                                                                     
 STATUS:  RESULTS - OVERTYPE TO MODIFY                                         
Db2conn        Accountrec( Txid )     ***Authid(          )  Authtype( Sign )***  Comauthid(          )   Comauthtype( Cuserid )  Comthreadlim( 0001 )   Comthreads(0000)  Connecterror( Abend )   Connectst( Connected )                                                      
Db2groupid(      )   ***Db2id( DB2  )***   Db2release(1010)  Drollback(Rollback)                                                         
Msgqueue1( CSMT )  Msgqueue2(      ) Msgqueue3(      ) Nontermrel( Norelease )                                                     
Plan( DEFAULT  )  Planexitname(          )  Priority( Equal )  Purgecyclem( 00 )                                                           
Purgecycles( 30 )        Resyncmember(              )   Reuselimit( 01000 )                                                         
***Signid( ABCDCICS )***
```

Comment: Try googling SQLCODE 922: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=db2+-922&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=u3CUWP-2DdDr8AeLvpbQBA#q=sqlcode+922

Comment: Thanks Bruce.... But since SignId is my region's ID, is it advisable to ask for the access on that or do I have to worry anything about from security perspective? I am new to CICS and still trying to get my head around in it. Why would JDBC connection need access to plan (Default)?

Comment: I have added an answer below

Comment: Did this question get answered by any of the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n922.html), SQLCODE -922 means you don't have authorization to use to a resource, in your particular case -- `PLAN ACCESS`. As to the resolution, the aforementioned manual suggests this (emphasis mine):

> If error-type is 'PLAN ACCESS', then the authorization ID associated with this connection is not authorized to use the specified plan name or the specified plan name does not exist. **See your system administrator**.

Comment: Yes, the manualI have seen, but I want to know what is the exact requirement I need to give to system adminstrator. Do I have to worry about transactional security and user security w.r.t to DB2 Connections or Can I just ask to provide the access to ABCDCICS which is my region's ID?

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to a comment (rather than the original question):

Thanks Bruce.... But since SignId is my region's ID, is it advisable to ask for the access on that or do I have to worry anything about
from security perspective? I am new to CICS and still trying to get my head around in it. Why would JDBC connection need access to plan (Default)

The above could be expanded into a separate question.

### Explanation of Cobol/Cics/Db2

My knowledge is 10 year old and is Cobol-Cics based, things have changed in the mean time. I will try and explain how things work in **Cics Cobol DB2** in a very simple manner (there may be minor inaccuracies or changes). Hopefully this will provide some back ground information

In Mainframe *Cobol DB2*, DataBase access is like [SQLJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLJ) in java. When a Cobol/DB2 program is compiled,  it gets split in 2; A Cobol part and a *SQL part* (**DBRM**). The *SQL part* (**DBRM**) which intern undergoes a *Bind* to become a [Package/Plan](http://ibmmainframes.com/about18282.html).
The *package/plan* is fancy name for a special type of `Compiled` SQL procedure.

```
 So
 
                      Calls                      Accesses DB
     Cobol-Program <-----------> Package/Plan  <----------------->   Data Base
                           (Special SQL Procedure)
```

In Cobol/DB2 its the *Package/Plan* that **needs** the **DataBase access**.
What happens is you give users access to certain programs (perhaps via a Menu system) and it is the programs/Plans that have the actual DB access. The Plans are given access to only what they need. The users do not need (and normally are not given) any DB access.

---

#### Java

Your Java access is built on top of the existing *Cobol* interfaces.

At a guess your Java SQL is being passed to **Plan** (SQL procedure) which does a `Dynamic` DB2 call.
It is this **Plan** (SQL procedure) that Needs the Database access.

It might be worth using SQL procedures for DB access ???

---

#### Why Cobol/DB2 works this way

This may sound convoluted but:

- In Cobol at a lot of sites it is all largely automatic. There are normally
  Compile/Bind procedures set-up and everything happens automatically
- Normally for Cobol-Plans, Data-Base Access path's are worked out at `Bind` time. Cobol/DB2 will keep using the same access paths until the next `Bind`. This makes for a stable System.

  I worked for a Company that moved from the Mainframe Cobol/DB2
  to Unix/Oracle Package. On the mainframe, for the most part every-thing ran smoothly while with Oracle every so often a 10 minute program would run for 6 hours and cause chaos.
- If you are using JDBC, DB2 would be evaluating access paths at run time

For Cobol/DB2 there are real reasons for how it all works. It is a
shame that  [SQLJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLJ) did not cath on. It would work better with CICS than JDBC.

---

#### Links

Some links that may be useful

- Try [Google relationship between program and plan in db2](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=relationship+between+program+and+plan+in+db2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9P-UWMnGDKfM8gf-8KnQBg)
- [Explanation of plan versus package](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/50502)
- [Compile / Bind /Plan](http://ibmmainframes.com/about18282.html)
- [more on plan/package](http://www.idug.org/p/fo/et/thread=39528)

Answer (score 0):

JDBC differs from many of the other methods of getting database information from z/OS because it is *dynamic*, i.e. the queries are not known ahead of time and are parsed and analysed at runtime (though things like [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) allow some pre-compilation to happen as well as being generally safer).

By contrast, most COBOL etc. SQL calls (as well as SQLJ) are *static*. The program is compiled, and equally the SQL statements that they contain are bound to the database as *packages* (which are named `<collectionID>.*` to distinguish them into different *collections*), and then are referred to at runtime by ID. Packages are bound into *plans*., high-level ways of referring to a set of packages. At each of these levels, there are numerous customisations that can be made, as well as access control permissions that can be applied - as you'll know since that's what you're running into.

The static way is what you might consider has been the 'default' way of interacting with DB2 on z/OS. What this means is that, even though you might be using dynamic SQL (JDBC), it still actually uses packages and plans, but in this case, the packages are capable of executing dynamic SQL. By default, the collection ID of the packages and the plan name are both `NULLID`. I suspect that you do not have access to use this plan.

I suggest the steps you need to take, by yourself or with your database administrator, are:

- Ensure that your database is set up to enable JDBC usage. Is anyone already using JDBC on that database? Check whether the JDBC packages already exist, most likely with a collection ID of `NULLID`. If not, follow the [instructions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_jccinstallwithdb2z.html) to enable them, particularly noting the `DB2Binder` step.
- Ensure that you have the ability to use that plan. By 'you', I mean the user ID that your CICS region is running the request as. It may be that the user does not have access to use the `NULLID` plan.
- If all else fails, do deeper problem diagnosis. See whether the request is being logged in the database's job, and whether you can see which plan the request was made with. [Set up tracing](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjcdig.html) on the Java end, to see how the request is being made.